# What is the cutoff frequency of a dielectric rectangular waveguide?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, fiber-optics, waveguide

I'm wondering if anyone know what is the cutoff frequency of a dielectric rectangular waveguide. The most papers and books I can find talking about the cutoff frequency of a rectangular waveguides are actually on the hollow metal rectangular waveguide, for which the cut off frequency is shown as [image]
But I couldn't find a exact expression of the calculation of the cutoff frequency of a DIELECTRIC rectangular waveguide. Does anyone have any idea of this? Thanks!